# Assertion Fail When Trying to Create Custom Adapter For DS.Store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Just upgreaded to ember1.0 and the newest ember-data. Now when I try to create my store I get this error.

> Assertion failed: You tried to set `adapter` property to an instance of `DS.Adapter`, where it should be a name or a factory

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: adapter.create()
});
```

What is the new/correct way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ember Data 1.0.beta.1 you don't have to extend from `DS.Store` anymore. Just extend your model from `DS.Model` and your adapter From `DS.RESTAdapter`. If your naming your models and adapters (and serializers) according to the following naming convention, they're wired up automatically.

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  // ...
});

App.PostAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  // ...
});
```

Also have a look at the Ember Data 1.0.beta.1 transition reference: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#per-type-adapters

Comment: That is true lulezi however I had some functionality I needed shared for all adapters. I believe setting what you set in the store becomes the 'base' type for all your typed adapters.

Comment: What about `DS.RestAdapter.reopen()`?

Comment: Yes, but that is only if you don't wanna use the default `DS.RESTAdapter` as your default adapter.

Answer (score 2):

You have in some place:

```
adapter = MyAdapter.create();
...
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: adapter.create()
});
```

You must to pass the class itself:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: MyAdapter
});
```

So ember will be able to inject the container in MyAdapter.

Comment: Marcio there is no difference from what I have and your code examples. Can you explain more?

Comment: Sorry @Rob just typed too quick, and forget to remove the create from MyAdapter. Just use `adapter: MyAdapter` and will work.

Comment: Yes that works. It now takes a type instead of a instance. This will be the 'base adapter' that all you type adapter will follow.

Comment: Ok. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
App.MyFancyAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: 'MyFancy'
});
```

Basically you reference your adapter with a string from its name minus 'Adapter'. See https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L117

Comment: You also could just put App.MyFancyAdapter. It does not need to be a string.